# bash script: extracting and converting files

Tags: bash, zip, rename

I would like to write a bash script that extracts files from a .zip file and converts them into text files - pretty much adds `".txt"` at the end of the file name as they are all text files but do not have an extension.

I am pretty much new to shell. I've found this:

```
cd /path/to/files
for i in *.gz
do
    gunzip $i
done
for i in *.zip
do
    unzip $i
done
```

I imagine it extracts the files, but how do I then rename/convert them?

Comment: You can use the [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command to find all files that doesn't end with `.zip` or `.gz`, and automatically rename the files to add the `.txt` suffix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use use `extglob` to find all files that don't have `.txt` extension:

```
shopt -s extglob

for f in !(*.txt); do
   mv "$f" "$f".txt
done
```

**PS:** You can also use `!(*.txt)` pattern to match all the files with no extension.

Comment: Of course, that will rename the Zip and GZip files as well.

Comment: Very true it will. I first wrote answer using this glob pattern: `!(*.txt|*.*)` but then re-read the question which had `they are all text files` so I assume that all non-text will files would have been moved away.

Comment: also `mv "$f{,.txt}` ;)